# I need to count letter frequency and save the letter and it's freq as variable

Tags: python-3.x

the file input I get looks like this.

```
TCCATCTACT
GCGCTTCCTG
TCCATCTACC
TGCGCCCTTA
TCGTACTATC
TTTCGCCACC
TCACGCTTAC
ACCCTGCCGC
CACCTACGCC
CTTCAGCACC
```

My current code is

```
def readFile(fileName):
    symbTable = dict()
    with open (fileName, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            c = Counter(line)
            symbTable ['A'] = c['A']
            symbTable ['C'] = c['C']
            symbTable ['T'] = c['T']
            symbTable ['G'] = c['G']
    print(symbTable)
    for sym, freq in symbTable.items():
        SymObjList = []
        SymObjList.append(SymbolObject(sym, freq, ""))
        print(SymObjList)
    return symbTable, SymObjList
```

The problem is that my program is only working for one line in the file. How can I get it to find the letter frequency throughout the entire file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close:

```
import collections

def readFile(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        counts = collections.Counter(char for line in infile for char in line)
    symObjList = []
    for nuc in "ATCG":
        symObjList.append(SymbolObject(nuc, counts[nuc], ""))
        print(nuc, "appears", counts[nuc], "times")

    return {k:counts[k] for k in "ATCG"}, symObjList
```

Comment: I tried using this code and it returns "NameError: name 'collections' is not defined" even though I have "from collections import *" in the beggining of my code

Comment: @Isaiah: That's because you didn't `import collections`. I figured I didn't need to include that line in my post, since you were using `Counter` in your code. My post has been updated to reflect this

Comment: Thank you very much man. I'm sure I'm only one of very many that are appreciative of the help you've given.

Comment: @Isaiah: no sweat! glad I could help. Consider marking an answer as accepted so that others know that the issue is closed.

Comment: when I return my symObjList it gives me four different list. The first one has a symbol object for A. The second list has a symbol object for A and T. The third list has a symbol object for A, T and C. The fourth has A, T, C, G. I only want the fourth list. Do you know why this has happened?

Comment: @Isaiah: I don't seem to be able to figure out why it's doing that. Is the returned dictionary of frequencies correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop trough the lines all together. If you call `lines = f.readlines()` before the loop and then loop trough `lines`, that should work.